# Can i download another operating system from the internet from an old release server?

Tags: command-line, server, 22.04, internet, laptop

I want to know if you can create a bootable usb stick, download another operating system and burn it into the usb from a old release server.

Comment: Yes, you can download them from https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ but one thing to remember that old releases are not supported here that are either End of Standard Support or End of Life.

Comment: The question is not very clear. (1) Do you already have a running old server and you want to download a current installation ISO? (2) Or do you wand to download the installation ISO of an older and unsupported version? The answer to both is yes. In any case you should not run and unsupported and unpatched server and connect it to the Internet.

Comment: @user68186 I'm referring to 1, I'm wondering whether it us possible or not

Comment: Yes it is possible. It is also possible (may not be likely) that your old and unsupported server may be infected with malware and they may compromise the installation USB.

Comment: @Terrance See my earlier comments and OP's response.

Comment: @user68186 Either way, it is a question dealing with either downloading an unsupported or creating a USB from an unsupported OS.  There is no guarantee that it will even work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that ISOs found on https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ may not boot on fully upgraded & secured machines (esp. if using secure uEFI)

eg. you may not get **22.04.2** or **20.04.5** media (*or older*) booting due to the *revoked* keys; with newer [22.04.3](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/) & [20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) in those cases having valid keys.  ISOs on that site can be used, but are *unpatched* and may not boot/install on modern security intended environments for this reason.

[Quoting from a link I provided](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/)

> Unlike previous point releases, 20.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64
> installer media after recent key revocations, re-enabling their usage
> on Secure Boot enabled systems.

ISOs found on https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ will likely include systems that are **not** on-topic on this site, and maybe a security risk, so use them wisely & off-line.

Comment: The 22.04 & 20.04 are used only as examples; same will apply with regards *revoked* keys for 18.04 & 16.04... I just opted to use the *newer* examples that were easier to find in my browser.. An example for 16.04 will be https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/ but that's now rather old; as I don't post notices once a release goes EOSS (2021-April for 16.04 or *xenial*) on Ubuntu Fridge, thus I don't know if later exists due to revoked keys  (*Pro or ESM releases come from Canonical*).

Comment: @user68186 to me details about writing a 16.04 ISO to thumb-drive are *clearly* off-topic, and I'll not provide any detail with regards that  (*not on this site anyway; as it's off-topic* ; https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)  FYI:  Yes you can download & use older ISO to upgrade to a *modern* & *supported* system, but I see no specific details with regard that in the actual question; it refers to 16.04 which would be a *poor* choice for doing this.

Comment: You can download any ISO from any system, there maybe more security risks involved if using a *deprecated* (EOL) system, but the way the question itself is written doesn't make that clear  (this is a Q&A site, not a forum).  A `wget` to download, then `dd` to write the ISO should work on any OS/release if security checks are performed to verify what was done (*ensure no compromises*)